# Minimum Salt Intake

Tags: salt

I am researching salt intake for the elderly.

According to WebMd (http://www.m.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/news/20100624/90-percent-in-us-get-too-much-salt-5-foods-blamed)

Americans on average should get a maximum of 1500mg sodium = .75 teaspoon salt

Middle aged, elderly, and African American should get maximum 2300mg sodium = 1 teaspoon

But there is no documentation on minimum intake requirements.

What is the minimum sodium required for the elderly and what is the minimum sodium requirements for the young?

Comment: There are many factors... for example, potassium counteracts sodium.. that's just one factor.

Comment: Humans evolved in a sodium-poor, potassium-rich environment, therefore our bodies are very good at retaining sodium and excreting potassium. It would be virtually impossible to not get adequate salt intake even if you never added a grain of salt to anything ever again. After all, our ancestors didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Recommended Dietary Allowances: 10th Edition](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK234935/)

> A minimum average requirement for adults can be estimated under
>   conditions of maximal adaptation and without active sweating...to 115
>   mg of sodium or approximately 300 mg of sodium chloride per day. In
>   consideration of the wide variation of patterns of physical activity
>   and climatic exposure, a safe minimum intake [of sodium chloride]
>   might be set at 500 mg/day [**~200 mg sodium/day**]

So, for adults (young or old), the minimum requirement is about 200 mg (0.2 g) of sodium per day or even just about 100 mg (0.1 g) without active sweating.

Comment: In other words, you'd get adequate salt from the first few bites of breakfast every morning. It almost wouldn't even matter what you eat for breakfast.